# Magento 2 errors on cache:flush cache:clean | Need to set permission to 777 afterwards

Tags: magento2

Everytime I run:

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

I get the following message when reloading the page:

> An error has happened during application run. See exception log for
>   details.

exception.log:

```
ain.CRITICAL: Exception: Warning: file_put_contents(/var/www/magento2/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---914_CONFIG_SCOPES): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/magento2/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php on line 663 in /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61
```

When I then run:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ pub/
```

The error is gone.

How could this happen everytime I clean cache and what should be done to back trace/solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of such type of issues is same: the user that run web-server differs from the user which runs console command.

### Preconditions

You should define what user run your web-server.

```
$ ls -la
```

This command could who creates `var/cache` and so on.

Let's decide that web-server run under `www-data` user.

### Solution 1

```
$ sudo -H -u www-data __some_command_here_
```

This format allows you to run the command under web-server user. So application will have same rights as a server (user `www-data`). 
So you command `php bin/magento cache:flush` transforms to

```
$ sudo -H -u www-data php bin/magento cache:flush
```

### Solution 2

Add web-server's user to your user to the same group.

```
$ id
uid=1001(ygl) gid=1002(ygl) groups=1002(ygl),112(nopasswdlogin)
```

- this one will show information about the current user.

  $ sudo usermod -a -G  www-data
- this command will add `www-data` to yourGroupName.